# Get formatted value in SELECT statement

Tags: abap

Is there a way to get the "Value" field from a Select statement? When using the `SELECT` in ABAP, I get the value like in "Value Unconverted".

Is there a special FM that I have to use to get the "Value" field?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the SELECT statement directly is not possible, you need to convert the value.

Go to SE11, enter the table name `PROJ`. Double click the data element `PS_INTNR`, double click the domain `PS_PSPNR`. There is a field 'Routine', here you should find the value `KONPD`. This is the conversion exit used for converting between input (unconverted, i.e. what are stored in DB) and output values (converted, i.e. what are shown on the screen).

If you double click this field, it will give you the function modules you can use for converting:

- `CONVERSION_EXIT_KONPD_INPUT`
- `CONVERSION_EXIT_KONPD_OUTPUT`

The bad news you have to convert each value separately, so if the data is in an internal table `LOOP/ENDLOOP` and call the FM.